# Fibonacci Spiral curve with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I've seen a few posts about creating a "[golden spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral)" with python but have so far failed at being able to convert the math and code in those posts into a geometry node tree that works.

I'd simply like to modify a curve (or mesh) line into a spiral using the fibonacci sequence using blender 3.4+. Anyone know I would accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried as far when it failed?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a shot at a reasonable interface to a [Golden Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral):

[image]

A start-angle of 0 will give a base inner-radius of 1. (You can start from a negative angle) The result can be given an overall scale.

[image]

[image]